# Where can I get Adobe Acrobat 64?

Tags: downloads, adobe-reader

Does anybody know where can I get Adobe Acrobat for 64 bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### all ubuntu versions - 64bit users

Currently there is no 64bit version of Adobe Reader available in the standard *Canonical Partners* repository.

The Adobe Reader package is actually a 32bit package and thus all the 32bit dependencies will be installed as well.

You will need to enable the *Canonical Partners* repository in *Software Sources* (search in Dash)

[image]

Then in a terminal you can update and install acrobat reader:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

Be warned - its a 180Mb+ install.

---

If 180Mb+ is considered a too sizeable install, then strong consideration should be given to using alternative PDF readers such as [evince [image: Install evince]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evince) or [okular [image: Install okular]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/okular)

Comment: For me it is even more: "After this operation, 252 MB of additional disk space will be used." This is not funny.

Comment: nope, on 13.10, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a 64bit version, at least not yet.
If you don't want to install all those i386 packages when installing from the canonical repository use the following method, but **beware, this is not guaranteed to work and/or might be broken after system updates**:

1. get the Adobe Reader deb package [from adobe.com](http://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions)
2. install it with:
   `sudo dpkg -i --force-all AdbeRdr*`
   The size of `/opt/Adobe` is 136Mb.
3. there will be unmet dependencies. Fix this with
   `sudo apt-get -f install`
   In my case this added 11Mb.

So in total this is **147Mb**. Installing from canonical would have added another 55Mb. As every system usually has different sets of packages installed, you might save more or less than my 55Mb.

In other words, unless space really is an issue, go with fossfreedom's answer.

Credits to [tony from ossramblings.com](http://www.ossramblings.com/acrobat_reader_crashes_in_linux_with_firefox) for the `--force-all` switch.

Comment: But this will remove all 64 bits programs.

Comment: The deb package is not available from adobe any more (it used to, I got it from there before). The dropdown now only contains Windows, OS X and Android.