# How do I install Adobe Acrobat Reader deb package downloaded from Adobe website?

Tags: software-installation, adobe-reader

I am new to Ubuntu, but I believe I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed correctly.  I am trying to install Acroread using `AdbeRdr9.4.6-1_i386linux_enu.deb` that I downloaded from the Adobe web site.  How do I do this?

Comment: Worth noting that Ubuntu comes with a PDF reader (`evince`, aka `Document Viewer`). Acrobat does have more features, but if all you want to do is read PDF files it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Why would you need adobe reader? **Evince document viewer** works perfectly in ubuntu and it do what you can do in adobe reader and more, it supports PDF, Postscript, djvu, tiff, dvi, XPS, SyncTex support with gedit, comics books (cbr,cbz,cb7 and cbt) and it is installed by default on ubuntu 12.10. So don't bother yourself installing adobe reader.

Comment: Evince doesn't show animations and some certain tests.

Comment: It also doesn't support forward and back buttons.

Comment: It also does'nt show annotations correctly, some documents are printed and/or displayed incorrectly, filling forms is not visually compatible with the adobe reader.

Comment: Evince is great but unfortunately there are some PDFs that are designed for Adobe Reader and won't work with another tool. i.e. https://bsaefiling1.fincen.treas.gov/DownloadSaveServlet?formName=NFFBAR.pdf

Comment: Evince also doesn't reproduce bugs in reader when your trying to help people find a workaround...

Comment: Evince refuses to print 2-up PDFs at the correct size for me (Ubuntu 14.04; Evince 3.10.3). Acrobat prints correctly. FWIW.

Comment: Also doesn't support writable forms

Comment: All of this info is old/obsolete.

Answer (score 84):

### All Ubuntu versions prior to 13.10

To install Adobe Acrobat you will need to enable the *canonical partners* repository in the Software Sources tab of Update Manager

[image]

Use *Dash* and search for *Software Sources* or *Software & Updates* in 13.04 and later.

If you don't see those options in Software Sources, you can use the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then in a terminal you can update and install acrobat reader:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

---

It is strongly recommended from a security point-of-view to use the version in the repositories.

If - for whatever reason - you wish to download directly from Adobe and install then the following instructions apply:

Using firefox navigate to:

- http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/

Choose the following options as shown in the image - i.e. download the *.deb* package

[image]

When the Download button is clicked:

[image]

Leave it at the default to open in Software Center where you can install it.

If you have set your downloads to automatically save in your Downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr*.deb
```

Comment: **NOTE** for 12.10 64bit users - this Q&A applies - http://askubuntu.com/a/70380/14356

Comment: I am on 13.10 and even with the partners repos I can't install the reader. Ideas?

Comment: Also not working on 14.04.

Comment: Is there an updated answer for this? (The site has changed it's format since 2011) Or possibly workaround using the Unix version.

Answer (score 79):

**REVISED:** 2016-Nov (*minor wording only*)

### **For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 16.10, 32- or 64-bit**

[ adapted from: http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-13-10.html ]

**Adobe Reader 9** is not in the 'Partner' repository for **13.10** (or later).

1. Download Adobe Reader (32-bit), from *Adobe* site:

   From here: [ftp.adobe.com .. reader .. 9.5.5](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb)

   Check MD5SUM after downloading, input

   ```
   md5sum AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
   ```

   the output should be

   ```
   88036c68998d565c4365e2ad89b04d51 AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
   ```
2. Open a command line, change to the directory containing the **.deb** file.
3. Install package, forcing to accept 32-bit version and any errors:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. Add the missing 32-bit libraries: (*skip this step for **32-bit***)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386 lib32stdc++6
   ```
5. (Optional) Run for first time, to get icon in Unity menu bar.

   ```
   acroread <path>/<MyDocument>.pdf
   ```

---

### **For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

1. Add 'Canonical Partner' repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
   ```
2. Update your system

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Adobe Reader, and font extensions

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y install acroread acroread-fonts
   ```
4. (Optional) Run for first time, to get icon in Unity menu bar.

   ```
   acroread <path>/<MyDocument>.pdf
   ```

Comment: `acroread-fonts` doesn't seem to be on 12.04. Where can it be found?

Comment: it is in the medibuntu ppa

Comment: acroread-fonts not located in ubuntu 13.04
+1 for the general approach for the release

Comment: I heard that there is no further development of reader for linux

Comment: **Same here.** Someone should develop an alternate file format / reader (*would serve then right*), or improve the open-source PDF readers (*might be a lost cause, keeping up*).

Comment: Adobe's site doesn't provide linux downloads any more.

Comment: In 14.04 to avoid some warnings I had to do: `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 ; apt-get download overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386 ; sudo dpkg --ignore-depends overlay-scrollbar:i386 -i overlay-scrollbar-gtk2_*_i386.deb` ------ It is not possible to use `sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386` because this package depends on non-existing `overlay-scrollbar:i386`. ------ Also `libdconf0:i386` and  `libdconf-dbus-0-0:i386` should probably be installed but they are not available in 14.04.

Comment: I have had similar issues, but then they did **not** re-occur when I later installed on different PC. *This is a version/regression issue ..*

Comment: @david6: Thanks the solution worked. But `How to make adobe the default reader of my PDF files? ` I cannot see it in the unity bar after the document is closed.

Comment: There is no 64 bit version of acroread?

Comment: That worked even less stablely, when Adobe was supporting it. *You need to make do with the 32-bit version, regardless of which OS version.*

Comment: I'd suggest running `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386` before the `dpkg` command.

Comment: Also, see here for an AppArmor profile to attempt to harden Acrobat Reader: https://github.com/seanlano/seanlano-apparmor/blob/master/apparmor.d/opt.Adobe.Reader9.bin.acroread

Answer (score 9):

For saucy (13.10), you can include the raring partner repository. This is how I did it:

```
sudo echo -e '# for acroread\ndeb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raring-partner.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread

apt-cache show acroread
# Package: acroread
# Architecture: amd64
# Version: 9.5.5-1raring1
# Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, acroread-bin, nspluginwrapper
# [...]

apt-cache policy acroread
# acroread:
#   Installiert:           9.5.5-1raring1
#   Installationskandidat: 9.5.5-1raring1
#   Versionstabelle:
#  *** 9.5.5-1raring1 0
#         500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring/partner amd64 Packages
#         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can I suggest to add the info, that one only needs to do the first three lines. And that rest is to show what has been installed (and is thus optional).

Comment: `sudo echo string > protected_file` doesn't work. Instead use `echo string | sudo tee protected_file`

Comment: This method also works for Trusty (14.04). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/455135/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-in-ubuntu-14-04 for a discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I combined above methods and so I can install Adobe Acrobat Reader on
*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus* and *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver*:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get -y install libxml2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 \
gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386 gtk2-engines:i386

sudo apt-get install ./AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Then one can launch it with `acroread`.

***Note:*** what makes Adobe Reader almost unique and useful - [it is its search in files](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037705/66509) (accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

Comment: Can confirm, works great for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Adobe is not going to support linux in the near future (see post [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9366167)), unless there is an increase in numbers of linux users requesting support. This can be done via filling the following Adobe feature request form: [Feature Request/Bug Report Form](http://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html).

As an alternative, you may want to switch to **Foxit** or **master pdf** readers, who are actually faster to open and provide more free features than Adobe reader.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.10 on amd64 seems to require

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -y install adobereader-enu
```

Without i386 in 64-bit env acroread gives `file not found` and GTK errors, so run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libicu-dev:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

This may be redundant as main bin is i386

```
sudo apt-get -y install gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-* libgtkmm-2.4-1c2 libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Answer (score 1):

Acroread is now available in Quantal's partner repo.

See this Launchpad bug:

- [acroread 9.5.1 is not installable on Ubuntu Precise amd64 system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/990761)

It says Precise in the title, but it applies to precise, quantal and raring.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
# sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.4.6-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

But I recommend evince as better pdf reader. It's the default in quantal.

Comment: Some PDFs must be viewed with Adobe Reader, unfortunately... https://bsaefiling1.fincen.treas.gov/DownloadSaveServlet?formName=NFFBAR.pdf

Comment: I like Evince's speed, but its rendering (e.g. applying kerning) is rather sub par.

Answer (score 0):

[NOrbert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032165/681688) worked for me, but only when I added the `--reinstall` option when installing the acroread package.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ./AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```