# How to install adobe reader .bin download from Adobe

Tags: software-installation, adobe-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Acrobat Reader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89127/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader)

I am having Ubuntu operating system.
I have downloaded file `AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i486linux_enu.bin` file from Adobe.
It is located in my Downloads directory.
I am a new user of linux.
Please could you provide STEP BY STEP instructions & commands to install adobe reader.

Answer (score 13):

If you downloaded Adobe-Reader from the Adobe website and wish to install it see below.

### Installing Adobe Reader .bin

First open your Downloads folder, then right click on the `AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i486linux_enu.bin` and select `Properties`.  Under the permissions tab tick / select `Allow Executing File As A Program`.

Next open a terminal and change to your Downloads folder:

```
cd Downloads
```

Then install Adobe Reader using :

```
sudo ./AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i486linux_enu.bin
```

Enter your password when prompted and wait for it to Install.

When prompted for the installation directory, press enter to accept the default.

Adobe Reader can then be started from the Dash, Desktop shortcut or by right clicking a .pdf file.

If running Ubuntu 64-bit, it may be necessary to install the 32-bit libraries.

```
 apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: You could also opt to use the command line to change the permissions instead of using Nautilus.  So instead of the first part to change the permissions after you `cd Downloads` you could do `chmod +x AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i486linux_enu.bin` and then proceed as directed after that.

Answer (score 6):

- Open the Ubuntu Software Center, and select Edit->Software Sources.
- Click on the "Other Software" tab, and check "Canonical Partners".
- Close Software sources, close Ubuntu Software Center, and open Ubuntu Software Center again
- Search for "acroread", select Adobe Reader or acroread (can't remember which shows up, same thing though), and click on Install (you might have to enter your password)

Comment: No need to install Synaptic for that. Just open **Ubuntu Software Center** Edit menu, Software Sources.

Comment: Oh, I never saw edit->software sources in USC... Thanks though, will update the post