# How do I download Adobe Flash on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, flash, adobe-reader

I'm having trouble on figuring out how to download Adobe Flash and Adobe reader on the newest version on Ubuntu 12.10, Can anyone help me?

Comment: To install *Adobe reader* look [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/89127/62483).

Comment: To install the *Adobe Flash Plugin* look [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/11/62483)

Answer (score 0):

It is rather simple; 
- open software center
- typ in the search box '**restricted extra's**' and choose the version for Ubuntu
- install the package

now you should have Flash installed. 
Adove reader is a package you really don't need; you can easily install via the software center software that suits your needs (there is a lot of software for this purpose)

Succes !