# Cannot reinstall Adobe Reader

Tags: 12.10, adobe-reader

I accidentally deleted the files under /opt/ which also included the directory Adobe where the reader was installed. Now I am trying to reinstall it by using the the command

```
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

In this after a few lines I get the following error

```
    amit@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install aroread
[sudo] password for amit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package aroread
amit@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install acroread
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nspluginviewer:i386 nspluginwrapper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acroread nspluginviewer:i386 nspluginwrapper
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/218 kB of archives.
After this operation, 649 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package nspluginviewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 173632 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nspluginviewer:i386 (from .../nspluginviewer_1.4.4-0ubuntu4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nspluginwrapper.
Unpacking nspluginwrapper (from .../nspluginwrapper_1.4.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package acroread.
Unpacking acroread (from .../acroread_9.5.5-1precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up nspluginviewer:i386 (1.4.4-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up nspluginwrapper (1.4.4-0ubuntu4) ...
plugin dirs:
nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
Auto-update plugins from /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Looking for plugins in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Auto-update plugins from /usr/lib/firefox/plugins
Looking for plugins in /usr/lib/firefox/plugins
Auto-update plugins from /root/.mozilla/plugins
Looking for plugins in /root/.mozilla/plugins
Setting up acroread (9.5.5-1precise1) ...
No LSB modules are available.
nspluginwrapper: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellinux/nppdf.so is not a valid NPAPI plugin
No LSB modules are available.
nspluginwrapper: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellinux/nppdf.so is not a valid NPAPI plugin
```

I am not sure what it means by LSB modules.

Comment: First correct your aroread typo and see if things don't magically start installing.  If that doesn't fix it follow this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89127/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader

Answer (score 0):

LSB modules are are Linux Standard Base modules.   You should be able to ignore those messages.  'lsb` is an installable package, if you want to install it.

For the nspluginwrapper messages you will need to find the plugin directory that has the link to the installation under /opt and remove them.   Those messages can likely be ignored as well.

`acroread` should be installed in the standard directories not /opt.  Shortcuts referring to the old installation will be broken.  `/usr/bin/acroread` should startup the reader.