# Getting the E-book reader

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

What are the popular e-book readers for Ubuntu? I am trying to download books in electronic format but I don't know any suitable e-book reader.

Answer (score 1):

Calibre is very good reader for .epub documents.

To install calibre from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

Or click the icon: [calibre[image: Install calibre]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/calibre)

Answer (score 1):

calibre ebook management software is excellent.

An ebook reader is included which handles a wide range of formats. calibre can convert between ebook formats too.

It's available in the Ubuntu repositories or at http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux.
calibre has a powerful range of tools, not least of which is an ebook server which your tablet and mobile can access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to Acrobat Reader, there is Acrobat Reader for Ubuntu. You'll find it from the PPAs.  To download and install it to your Ubuntu system, follow the instructions here:

[How do I install Adobe Acrobat Reader deb package downloaded from Adobe website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89127/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader)