# Adobe Reader for Linux discontinued

Tags: adobe-reader

I can't find the download for adobe reader any more. I installed it about a month or two ago on my other machine. AM I BLIND?

http://get.adobe.com/reader/download/

Comment: Just answered this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89127/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader

Comment: The latest version - Adobe Reader 9.5.5 is still available on the Adobe's servers through a direct link: http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb

Answer (score 4):

Adobe has announced its future plans for Flash and AIR and Linux isn't part of them. Flash will still, however, be available to Linux desktop users who use Google's Chrome Web browser.

And I think that has also something to do with Acrobat Reader, since its no longer available for download from their site.  If you still want Acrobat Reader version 9.5.5, you can get it [on Adobe's FTP server](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/).