# Trouble downloading Adobe Reader in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, adobe-reader

I been trying to install adobe reader from Synaptic Package Manager but I keep getting a error message. Are any of you experiencing the same error or bug? I even tried downloading it from the Terminal but no dice! What do you guys think it could be? The website is no help since Linux is not listed as one of the OS to download, what's up with that?

Comment: The fact that the website has no Linux version of Acrobat is a clue...  It does not run in Linux.  There are several alternatives though.  Most PDF files can be read with Document Viewer, or if you open your Software Center, and type PDF in the search, you will be presented with several others.

Comment: Just answered this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89127/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader