# Install Adobe Acrobat XI with wine

Tags: wine, winetricks, adobe-acrobat

Adobe Acrobat XI has a [silver rating on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=847), meaning it should work, right?

I right click acrobat.exe, and the installation wizard pops up and installs successfully with no errors. However, I tick the 'open application' box at the end of the installation and...nothing happens.

Adobe Acrobat isn't appearing in my list of installed apps. Basically it's not working at all, despite a very promising installation.

WineHQ has this to say on installing Acrobat XI:

> **What works**
>
> opening documents, OCR. No problems by now.
> Acrobat asked me to install Adobe Application Manager
> (http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4773), so i
> did installed and no problem since then.
>
> **What does not**
>
> Isn't able to install. As first review said, use
> winetricks atmlib , and copy the acrobat folder into proper .wine
> folder.

Wine beginner here. Could someone explain what he means by `use winetricks atmlib , and copy the acrobat folder into proper .wine folder.` Could someone guide me through those steps **slowly**? Thanks. Greatly appreciated, really want to get acrobat working :)

Comment: Not an answer to the Wine question, thus making this a comment - but is there a special reason for needing Acrobat 11? I'm using Acrobat 9.5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 very happily. Instructions for installing (via PPA) are on [the "UbuntuHandbook" site](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-14-10/). Easy peasy.

Comment: Also (just noticed too late for edit) see the [AskUbuntu Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/a/89129/38585) on installing Acrobat.

Comment: it will be better if you install Adobe reader version 9 from some website that keeps old software. that version is made for linux. you wont have any problem in installation

Comment: thanks all, but I need a version of acrobat so I can leave comments in my pdfs. I've managed to get reader working in Ubuntu:)

Comment: You can try installing it using PlayOnLinux. (https://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

Comment: Adobe Acrobat XI is not supported by PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1049725/57576

Answer (score 8):

I'm the person who wrote [the first test results](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30353&iTestingId=84421) of Adobe Acrobat XI Pro on Wine App database.

You can't install the program using current, official Wine release. If you want install it with - and only with - Wine, you will need a MSI "hack patch" which bypasses some custom MSI action calls required basically by any modern Adobe installer.

The patch for Wine is provided [here](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18070)

The downside is that, at the moment, the patch is rejected from official Wine mainstream releases. However, you can apply it to Wine source code and compile Wine by yourself. After you've compiled Wine and installed it into your system, you should be able to install Adobe Acrobat XI Pro without issues. The patch works also for other Adobe software, such as

- Adobe Audition (CS5.5 & CS6)
- Adobe Premiere Pro CS3

(Wine 1.7.36 + patch applied)

I've compared/analyzed the first installation method I described on Wine AppDB ("Copy all files from Windows OS"), and the "MSI hack patch" method. Both of them work: all needed Acrobat files are installed, whichever method you decide to use.

Winetricks requirements for the patch method are as follows:

```
winetricks msxml3 msxml6 wininet ie8 vcrun6 atmlib
```

On winecfg, set your Windows version to "Windows 7", before running the Acrobat Installer.

If  you have troubles with printing in Acrobat XI Pro, set riched20 override to "builtin" instead of "native" on winecfg.

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: most of those links to microsoft files are starting to break now, so winetricks is getting 404 errors

Answer (score 1):

Install the atmlib library by running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo winetricks atmlib
```

As for copying the folder over, this refers to a bug in Acrobat's installer which prevents it from copying the folders into the relevant directory. The alternative is to copy the folders from a windows computer that already has Acrobat installed on it. However, it sounds like you managed to install Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to this question, but I gave up on installing Acrobat and instead installed [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/). I had to open the .exe with wine, but let me tell you Foxit is incredible!

- Free for personal use
- More features than acrobat
- Far better looking than linux-native free pdf readers

Comment: I think there is a build available for Linux anyway :)

Comment: While Foxit is great, it does not offer Form Filling under Linux AFAIK.