# How to make Adobe PDFMaker (Acrobat Pro XI) working with Microsoft Office 2007 using winetricks?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, adobe, microsoft-office, winetricks

I have installed Microsoft Office 2007 with help of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/998783/66509) using WineTricks.

I need to integrate Adobe Acrobat Pro XI into Word to produce high quality PDFs.

So I have a question - how to make Acrobat PDFMaker working on Ubuntu using Wine?

<sup>And please do not suggest me to use LibreOffice for this purpose. There are some use-cases where Acrobat Pro is needed.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can install Adobe Acrobat Pro XI by the method similar to the [MathType installation](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043961/66509) (to the same *WINEPREFIX*) and following [this answer about Acrobat Pro](https://askubuntu.com/a/586407/66509) by steps below:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
export WINEPREFIX=~/.local/share/wineprefixes/office2007pro
sh ./winetricks msxml3 msxml6 wininet ie8 vcrun6 atmlib
wine SETUP.EXE
```

Then it will add *Acrobat* panel to the Word 2007 ribbon:

[image: Acrobat Ribbon]

and clicking *Create PDF* will start PDF creation process with progress bar window

[image: Acrobat PDFMaker]

and will finish by showing PDF document.

Note: method is fully-functional, but embedded Mathtype equations look weird in resulting PDF document.