# opening http://u.bb/59B while installing microsoft office 2007 using wine program loader and then installation stops?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Whenever I tried to install Microsoft Office 2007. It always opens http://u.bb/59B while installing microsoft office 2007 using wine program loader and then installation stops. This issue is same with playonlinux. Then shows Binary not found for WINWORD.EXE,WINEXCEL.EXE etc.

Comment: You have to get correct OFFICE12.iso and install it using PlayOnLinux, I think.

Comment: You of course have visited the Wine web site to see if that program is supported and any special install instructions. Since that is 15 year old software intended for Windows XP I doubt it is supported.

Comment: @David your comments are sometimes very confusing. Please take them with yourself, do not spread them here. Using Office 2007 with [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-436-Microsoft_Office_2007.html) is absolutely possible with PlayOnLinux, moreover one can integrate [MathType](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043961/66509) and [Acrobat Pro](https://askubuntu.com/a/1045287/66509) here. OP may use wrong ISO file, try https://archive.org/details/office12.aspx .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Wine support Office 2007?](https://askubuntu.com/a/258717/66509) .