# Has anyone installed adobereader-enu on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

Has anyone installed adobereader-enu on Ubuntu 17.10?

I was running AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386i386linux_enu.deb before I purged JPEG due to some silly issue - now I cannot install the reader. The PlayOnLinux thing just breaks every time, so I didn't want to go there again.

Comment: See solution - https://askubuntu.com/a/1032165/66509 . Also I recommend to upgrade to 18.04 LTS.