How does one install Adobe Acrobat 9 on Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04?
The old recipes, that have worked for a while, like this one, this another and even this one no longer work.
Does anyone know how to instal it on modern distributions?
Observe that my question is NOT about installation of Windows software under Wine, it is about installing a Linux version of Acrobat Reader without using Wine.

Adobe Acrobat is without support since July 26th 2013 - which is more than 10 years. So you may not want to use it all today.

Fo what reason? Security? Malicious PDF files? It is by far the best PDF renderer on Unix, even to this date. I sort os use it only offline.

@karel Installation directly on Ubuntu and under Wine are two very different beasts. In the question you mention, the OP asked for TWO installations "Adobe Reader 9 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC under Wine". You answered only the second half of that question and my question above is the other half.

This question is similar to: How do I install Adobe Acrobat Reader deb package downloaded from Adobe website?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The answer below is pretty much the same as https://askubuntu.com/a/1032165/158442

With the exception of what I note down below on how to deal with some of the error messages, and of the fact that it does not set the architecture (sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 / sudo apt update) which makes it lireally not usable. So the answer down below here, by @kyodake is much better and almost complete.

That part is covered in other answers there as well.

Tell me which answer you are refeering to and I'll show you what is wrong for 22.04 and 24.04. I have tried them all and they all fail in different ways. The one you point above just plain does not work with a fresh installation of Ubuntu.

To install Adobe Acrobat 9:
Open the terminal and enter the following command:
wget -O ~/adobe.deb ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb

Enable i386 architecture enter the following command:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update

Install all prerequisites by enter de following command:
sudo apt install libxml2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386

Install the Adobe Acrobat Reader package downloaded previously, by enter de following command:
sudo dpkg -i ~/adobe.deb


I get two error messages when running the command: `(acroread:83844): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:09:47.042: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
(acroread:83844): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:09:47.042: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",`  but otherwise IT WORKS! Do you know what they are ?

I just found out that doing sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard:i386 will clear the "pixmap" and now I only have the "adwaita" message left.

@TeXApprentice warnings are non-issues. You can ignore them if all else works.  However keep in mind that Adobe Acrobat 9 is old and unlikely to support all new PDF features.

Thanks, good to know. I am aware that it is old and does not support new stuff, but on rendering it is still the best among all available on Linux, specially on kerning.

@kyodake I have one machine where things went a little bit different. This one was originally at 22.04 and was upgraded to 24.04 and after running the command I get: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
