# Multiple errors while installing acroread on Ubuntu 12.10 64b

Tags: 12.10, adobe-acrobat

From [here](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/) I obtained the latest deb file, double-click that opens `Software Center` and click `install`. I got:

```
The package is of bad quality
The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath.
```

Detail providd is posted [here](http://pastebin.com/t8Gf1GtE). On the same popped up window there's an option to "ignore and install" which I very much hesitate to go on with.

Also with the same .deb file I tried from commandline as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/213592/24203):

```
sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.4.6-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

which yields:

```
userdayo@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.5.3-1_i386linux_enu.deb 
(Reading database ... 197960 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking adobereader-enu (from AdbeRdr9.5.3-1_i386linux_enu.deb) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'AdbeRdr9.5.3-1_i386linux_enu.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing AdbeRdr9.5.3-1_i386linux_enu.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread' to '/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 AdbeRdr9.5.3-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

`ia32-libs` is installed per suggestion [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AcrobatHowTo).

Env) Ubuntu 12.10 (tested on 2 machines, 1 is notebook 1 is virtual machine) 64 bit

Any idea to work around? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this post? [Where can I get Adobe Acrobat 64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70372/where-can-i-get-adobe-acrobat-64/70380#70380)

This what worked for me. 
Just type this into the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

as it's precise repository it might cause some packages conflicts

Comment: Although I described & labelled that I'm using `Quantal`, I tried your suggesting w/quantal, and didn't work to be told `"E: Package 'acroread-common' has no installation candidate"`.

Comment: Yep. it's precise rep but I did it myself on quantal 64bit and it worked without any errors. However it's ver. 9.4, a bit older one. Later later I have encountered an opinion that it is not the best idea to install it from older repos because it might mess the thing up.

Comment: +1 I see, at least good to know it worked although I won't try `precise` as you said.

Answer (score 0):

This package is not well made, ownership of files is wrong, permissions are wrong on some files. try another deb there is a 9.5.3.

You might be better off using something like envince? or some free alternative.