# Acroread Package not Found

Tags: 12.10

Just installed Ubuntu 12.10. Trying to install adobe acrobat reader with the command

```
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

My package settings and software sources are attached as screenshots. But it can't find the package acroread. Please help. I have even installed ubuntu-restricted-extras.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible deplicate: [Multiple errors while installing acroread on Ubuntu 12.10 64b](http://askubuntu.com/q/237516/25656)

Comment: @vasa1 Fundamentally that was about how the Software Center identified it as bad quality and wouldn't install it. This is different--the Software Center is not being used; the problem is the necessary repository is not enabled. The answers there don't really apply--but yours does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Install Adobe Acrobat Reader in Ubuntu12.10/12/04/Linux Mint](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-adobe-acrobat-reader-in-ubuntu.html), you need to do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

But note that the [Launchpad page here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread) does **not** list a package for quantal (12.10).

---

acroread was either removed from quantal or was not made for quantal so changing precise to quantal in above instruction OR checking the box in the image posted in the question in the tab 1 to the right (named Other Software) will NOT work. You need to use the precise repo or download it straight from adobe.com

Comment: nope keep it. He wants acroread so he can use the precise repo for it ;) nothing wrong with the answer. Here have an edit ;) @vasa1

Answer (score 0):

Acroread is now available in Quantal's partner repo.

See this Launchpad bug:

- [acroread 9.5.1 is not installable on Ubuntu Precise amd64 system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/990761)

It says Precise in the title, but it applies to precise, quantal and raring.